# Previous versions tab from Volume Shadow Services

Tags: windows-10, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy, previous-versions

In Windows 7 I had the following habit:

- Create a system restore point (which creates a shadow copy)
- Make some heavy changes to files
- Open [Properties > previous versions > Timestamp] of a folder for which I was interested in changes
- Copy the UNC path (for example \localhost\D$@GMT-2020.09.23-00.02.51) which exposes the shadow copy to my preferred sync tool to compare the changes with the current folder

Unfortunately in Windows 10, [Properties > previous versions] is reserved for some backup tool and I can only access shadow copys with tools like shadow copy viewer (Source: [Microsoft forums](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2ebc2245-f5a4-4883-9762-f93f8f21d19b/previous-versions-not-working-in-windows-10?forum=win10itprogeneral)). The UNC path isn't avaliable (despite Volume shadow service being turned on).

Now I am looking for an alternative which mounts a shadow copy at some UNC path for my sync tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution dug deep here: [Aaron Mason](https://superuser.com/a/1462940/1205701) by using symlinks:

- `cmd` as Admin
- `vssadmin list shadows`
- Look for text at correct system restore point after "Shadow Copy Volume:" and copy it
- `mklink /d C:\vsstest [Paste the text here]\` (for example `mklink /d C:\vsstest \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2\` )
- Use the Path C:\vsstest for your tasks
- If done you can delete the Link with `rmdir C:\vsstest`

Comment: I still wonder why going directly to \\?\GLOBALROOT\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy2\ doesn't work.